# How to add Material-UI form with Steppers in React-Amin Create Component

Tags: material-ui, create-react-app, react-admin

I have a very long form in my [React-Admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) app. 
I would like to add the form elements to a stepper.

From Material-UI, they provide an example of [Steppers](https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/)

What id like to be assisted on is

1. How to add components such as  to the stepper's function

> getStepContent()

2. How to wrap all input components into a form
3. Avoid moving to the next step if form in ine step is not validated.

   function getStepContent(stepIndex) {
     switch (stepIndex) {
       case 0:
          return 'Select campaign settings...';
       case 1:
         return 'What is an ad group anyways?';
       case 2:
         return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
       default:
         return 'Uknown stepIndex';
     }
   }

   class HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper extends React.Component {
     state = {
       activeStep: 0,
     };

   handleNext = () => {
       this.setState(state => ({
         activeStep: state.activeStep + 1,
       }));
     };

   handleBack = () => {
       this.setState(state => ({
         activeStep: state.activeStep - 1,
       }));
     };

   handleReset = () => {
       this.setState({
         activeStep: 0,
       });
     };

   render() {
       const { classes } = this.props;
       const steps = getSteps();
       const { activeStep } = this.state;

   ```
   return (
     <div className={classes.root}>
       <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
         {steps.map(label => {
           return (
             <Step key={label}>
             <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
             </Step>
           );
         })}
       </Stepper>
       <div>
         {this.state.activeStep === steps.length ? (
           <div>
             <Typography className={classes.instructions}>All steps completed</Typography>
             <Button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</Button>
           </div>
         ) : (
           <div>
             <Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
             <div>
               <Button
                 disabled={activeStep === 0}
                 onClick={this.handleBack}
                 className={classes.backButton}
               >
                 Back
               </Button>
               <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleNext}>
                 {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : Next'}
               </Button>
             </div>
           </div>
        )}
       </div>
     </div>
   );
   ```

   }
   }

   HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper.propTypes = {
     classes: PropTypes.object,
   };

   export default withStyles(styles(HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper);

Answer (score 3):

Incase anyone ever gets stuck on this, I found a nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY) on youtube that you can easily follow.